# CSS: How to ensure image completely fills container?

Tags: css, image

I would like to ensure an image fills the entire space of its container. In [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cagross/pen/OzGzGw), how can I ensure the first image fills it's container proportionately? If some cropping occurs, that is OK. The catch is that I would like the width on each  to remain 100%, so the image sizes scale down evenly with screen size.

I have tried every option of `object-fit` but none resolve the issue.

Using `background-image` is not desirable in this case.

My code is:

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid red;
   max-width:400px;
}
.shopping-cart-img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="www.google.com">
            <img class="shopping-cart-img" src="https://dev.horizonhomes-samui.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </td>
            <td>
          <a href="www.google.com">
            <img class="shopping-cart-img" src="https://dev.horizonhomes-samui.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1-2.jpg" alt="">
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: @Martin ah right, thanks.  Stand by...

Comment: Could you elaborate on why using a css background image is not an option? That seems like the ideal solution.

Comment: @DBS If I use `background-image`, am I able to set an alt text for the image?

Comment: @cag8f why do you need alt text? And you can have a transparent overlay image with an `alt` element `:-)`

Comment: Not directly, but you could imitate the same thing in a number of ways. E.g. a `title` on the element with the background image, or `aria-label`s if you're working on accessibility. (Or with an overlay as Martin suggests)

Comment: @Martin in the future, for SEO purposes, we'd like to add alt text to all of these images.  The transparent overlay option could be viable.  But would that mean the page loads the same image twice?

Comment: @cag8f it would load the transparant (ie small file size) overlay once and apply it numerous times.

Comment: @Martin OK got it.  But why would it apply it numerous times?  It seems like it only needs to be applied once.  Or are you saying that it will be applied numerous times only if I display that particular image numerous times?

Comment: well as many times as you want to put an ALT over an image. .....

Comment: OK right, got it.  In case I go that route, do you have a link that describes this method?  Or is it as simple as setting the opacity of the existing <img> to 0?

Answer (score 3):

`object-fit` won't work in `table-cell`, you need to make the element a block level element, so you can set it `(inline)-block`

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid red;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: block
}

/* Desktop sizes (above 600px) */

.shopping-cart-img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block /* remove white-space from inline elements*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <img class="shopping-cart-img" src="https://dev.horizonhomes-samui.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="www.google.com">
        <img class="shopping-cart-img" src="https://dev.horizonhomes-samui.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1-2.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `.shopping-cart-img` should have a `width` property, having `max-width` without a width is buggy on certain browsers

Comment: @Martin why is that?

Comment: hahaha if only I knew..... but     **`>`** IE10 and IE11 do not appear to support overriding min-width or max-width values using the initial (ie unset) value. **`>`**
    max-width doesn't work with images in table cells in IE.

Comment: ( I have also found from my own experience that sometimes maximums are not set if the default width is not actually specified. )

Comment: It's worth remembering that `object-fit` isn't supported by any version of IE, so you may want to include some graceful fallbacks if using it. https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: @Martin did you read my answer? table-cell is no longer a table-cell but instead is a block level element

Comment: @dippas Am I correct that your solution has images displayed one on top of the other, rather than side by side?  If so, I was hoping to keep them side-by-side.  Would that be possible?

Comment: @cag8f use `inline-block` along  with ` vertical-align:top`

Comment: @dippas `inline-block` on both elements, or just one? I'm able to get the images side-by-side again, but they are of different heights (codepen here: codepen.io/cagross/pen/BJXZYg).

Answer (score 0):

Give your parent element some height and the width and height 100% to your image.